# $y '' + y = \cos^2x$ using variation of parameters.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, proof-verification

The book says the answer is $\displaystyle y=C_1\cos x+C_2\sin x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6}\cos2x$, but the particular solution I'm getting is totally different.

Comment: It's possible your solution is the same, just looks different - that happens with trig functions. Or it could be you made an error. Nobody can say anything  about any of this since you don't bother to tell us what solution you got, or how you got it

Comment: Please show your solution.

Comment: PArticular solution i got is : -xcosx/2 - sin2xcosx/ 4 - sin^4x /3 + sin^2x

Comment: The answer given in the book is correct. May be, you could show your steps. I don't see how you could have an $x$ in front of the particular solution.

Comment: Is cosx/2 supposed to be $\cos(x)/2$ or $\cos(x/2)$? Is sin2x supposed to be $\sin(2x)$ or $\sin^2(x)$?

Comment: Its (xcos(x))/2 - sin(2x)cos(x)/ 4 - sin^4(x) /3 + sin^2(x)

Comment: solution goes like:
 -cos(x) * integral of (sin(x) * cos^2(x)  + sin(x) * integral of cos^3(x) 
and then i get the answer i wrote above

Comment: @AsadQureshi, please share your detailed solution. It seems like you had some mistake. BTW, writing $\displaystyle \cos^2x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)$ and finding two particular solutions might be easier.

Comment: my solution goes like:
= -cos(x) * integral of (sin(x) * cos^2(x) + sin(x) * integral of cos^3(x) .

 = -cosx((1/2(x) + sin2(x) /4 )   + sin(x) integ of (cos(x) ( 1/2 + cos(2x)/2) .
 = -xcos(x))/2 - sin(2x)cos(x)/ 4  + cosx * integ of (1- sin^2(x))  here i apply subsition u = sin x
 
Then finally 
 = -xcos(x))/2 - sin(2x)cos(x)/ 4  - sin^4(x) /3 + sin^2(x)

Comment: An obvious first step would be to write the equation as y''+ y= cos(2x)+ 1.

Comment: @AsadQureshi: Please add further (long) insights into the question to the question text by adding a section with appropriate header. It is easier to write and easier to read.

Comment: i found my mistake and got the right answer. thankyou all for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out before, $\cos^2(x)= \cos(2x)+ 1$.  Since the general solution to the homogeneous equation, $y''+ y= 0$ are $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, we look for a solution of the form 
$$
y(x)= u(x)\cos(x)+ v(x)\sin(x).
$$

Then 
$$
y'(x)= u'(x)\cos(x)- u(x)\sin(x)+ v'(x)\sin(x)+ v(x)\cos(x).  
$$
Additionally, require that 
$$u'(x)\cos(x)+ v'(x)\sin(x)= 0.$$
That reduces to 
$$y'(x)= -u(x)\sin(x)+ v(x)\cos(x).$$
Differentiating again, 
$$y''= -u'(x)\sin(x)- u(x)\cos(x)+ v'(x)\cos(x)- v(x)\sin(x).$$
  Then 
$$y''+y= -u'(x)\sin(x)+ v'(x) \cos(x)= \cos(2x)+ 1.$$
That, together with 
$$u'(x)\cos(x)+ v'(x)\sin(x)= 0,$$ 
gives two equations to solve for $u'$ and $v'$.  Multiplying the first equation by $\cos(x)$, 
$$-u'(x)\sin(x)\cos(x)+ v'(x)\cos^2(x)= \cos(x)\cos(2x)+ \cos(x),$$ 
and the second equation by $\sin(x)$, 
$$u'(x)\sin(x)\cos(x)+ v'(x)\sin^2(x)= 0,$$
 and adding, 
$$v'(x)= \cos(x)\cos(2x)+ 1.$$
To integrate that, use the sum and difference formulas: 
$$\cos(3x)= \cos(x+ 2x)= \cos(x)\cos(2x)- \sin(x)\sin(2x)$$ 
and 
$$\cos(x)= \cos(-x)= \cos(x- 2x)= \cos(x)\cos(2x)+\ sin(x)\sin(2x)$$ 
and, adding, 
$$2\cos(x)\cos(2x)= \cos(3x)+ \cos(x)$$ 
so 
$$\cos(x)\cos(2x)= (\cos(3x)+ \cos(x))/2.$$

---

Are you required to use "variation of parameters"?  Since the right hand side is $\cos(2x)+ 1$, "undetermined coefficients" works much more simply.  Look for a solution of the form 
$$y= A \cos(2x)+ B.$$
Then 
$$y''= -4A \cos(2x)$$ 
so that 
$$y''+ y= -4A\cos(2x)+ A\cos(2x)+ B= -3A \cos(2x)+ B= \cos(2x)+ 1.$$  Take $A= -1/3$ and $B= 1$.

Comment: i found my mistake and got the right answer. thankyou all for you help

Answer (score 2):

You should remind yourself how **variation of parameter** works

Given, non-homogenous ODE, $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y = g(x)$

> *how does the method works?*
>
> replace constants in the complementary solutions $$y_c = c_1y_1+c_2y_2$$ by functions $$y_p = u_1y_1+u_2y_2$$ and find the functions $u_1,u_2$ by substitute $y_p$ into $$y"+Py'+Qy=g$$ and obtain the system of
>
> $$y_1u_1'+y_2u_2' =0$$ $$y_1'u_1'+y_2'u_2' =g(x)$$
>
> Solve,
>
> $$u_1' = \frac{-y_2g(x)}W, u_2' = \frac{y_1g(x)}W$$ where $W$ is Wronskian of $y_1,y_2$ and solve for $u_1,u_2$

Comment: i have done exactly the same look at my soluton in the comment above

Comment: check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491578/help-with-a-differential-equation-variation-of-parameters-wrong-answer?rq=1